# Items from first stack can't reach second stack in C

Tags: c

My task is make the first stack which contains the letters "PASCAL" one by one to make it "LASCAP" by using 2 more stacks.  What my problem is, is that when i try to pop from first stack to the second, even though the items get out from first stack, second stack doesn't get any of them, making them both empty

```
typedef struct{
int Top;
StackElementType Element[StackLimit];} // representation of stack
StackType; 
int main(){
Push(&StackA,'P'); // pushing the items
Push(&StackA,'A');    
Push(&StackA,'S');
Push(&StackA,'C');
Push(&StackA,'A');
Push(&StackA,'L');  

for (i=0; i<7; i++)
Pop(&StackA,&StackB.Element[i]); // popping from first to second stack
return 0;
}
void Push(StackType *Stack, StackElementType Item)
{
if (!FullStack(*Stack)) {   //item push in stack function
    Stack -> Top++;
    Stack -> Element[Stack -> Top] = Item;
    } 
    else
    printf("Full Stack..."); 
}
void Pop(StackType *Stack, StackElementType *Item) //popping items function
{
if (!EmptyStack(*Stack)) {
    Stack -> Top--;
    *Item = Stack -> Element[Stack -> Top];
   } 
   else
    printf("Empty Stack...");
 }
```

Comment: *it's not the full code, it's the part with the problem  i have

Comment: Elements should **only** be used inside Push and Pop.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two issues:

you don't push elements into `stackB` but assign its elements directly:

```
for (i=0; i<7; i++)
    Pop(&StackA,&StackB.Element[i]);
```

That  doesn't affect `stackB.Top` and thus a subsequent `Pop()` wouldn't return anything

In `Push()` you have:

```
    Stack -> Top++;
    Stack -> Element[Stack -> Top] = Item;
```

so after the last character pushed, `stackA.Top` should be 6 and `Element[0]` will never be used, but only `Element[1]` to `Element[6]`. But in `Pop()`, it's:

```
    Stack -> Top--;
    *Item = Stack -> Element[Stack -> Top];
```

So the first element popped is `Element[5]` which is 'A' in your case

Comment: when i debug it, it shows that stackB gets the letters ACSAP, without the L, but yet when i try to print it to check if it really gets the items, it shows that the stack is empty

Comment: tthat's not really suprising, if stackB.Top isn't set

Comment: what do you mean it's not set.  By creating the stack, stack.Top get's the value -1